# Cucumber + Capybara + Selenium firefox opens example.com not my app 

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, selenium, cucumber, capybara

I've been using cucumber + webrat but needed extra Rails 3 compatability and javascript testing so changed to capybara + selenium. Currently I'm on Rails 3.0.7, Cucumber 0.10.2, caybara 1.0.0.beta1.

Problem: When I run a javascript scenario firefox opens "http://www.iana.org/domains/example/" or "www.example.com" instead of my rails app.

I'm sure it's just a small setting I'm missing, but I can't find it and this has had me stumped for a couple days now.

Anyway, my gemfile reads:

```
group :development, :test do
  gem 'cucumber'
  gem 'cucumber-rails', ">= 0.3.2"
  gem 'pickle'
  gem "launchy"
  gem "rspec-rails"
  gem "Selenium"
  gem "selenium-client"
  gem "selenium-webdriver"
  gem "database_cleaner"
  gem "factory_girl_rails"
  gem "capybara"
  gem "escape_utils"
end
```

The feature is:

```
  @wip
  @javascript
  Scenario: Calculate 1 recipe and be deducted a credit
    Given the following page records
      | name | permalink |
      | home | home      |
    And the following role records
      | name       |
      | SuperAdmin |
      | Admin      |
      | Customer   |
    When  I register "adam" with password "password"
    And I go to the index
    Then I should see "5 credits"
```

The step that opens the firefox window:

```
    When /^I am logged in as "([^"]*)" with password "([^"]*)"$/ do |username, password|
  unless username.blank?
    visit(root_path)
    fill_in "user_session_username", :with => username
    fill_in "user_session_password", :with => password
    click_button "login"
    page.should have_content("Successfully logged in!")
  end
end
```

my features/support/env.rb:

```
   require 'cucumber/rails'
    require 'factory_girl'
    require 'ruby-debug'
    require 'selenium/client'
    # require 'capybara/cucumber' commented out because it doesn't want to work with it in
    Capybara.default_driver = :selenium

    Capybara.server_boot_timeout = 50
    Capybara.default_selector = :css

    begin
      DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation
    rescue NameError
      raise "You need to add database_cleaner to your Gemfile (in the :test group) if you wish to use it."
    end
```

command prompt says:

```
    When I register "adam" with password "password"     # features/step_definiti
ons/web_steps.rb:229
      no link with title, id or text 'register' found (Capybara::ElementNotFound
)
      (eval):2:in `click_link'
      ./features/step_definitions/web_steps.rb:232:in `/^I register "([^"]*)" wi
th password "([^"]*)"$/'
      features\credit_behaviour.feature:30:in `When I register "adam" with passw
ord "password"'
```

I'm fairly new to Rails and to Ruby so be easy on me with any suggestions please, saying that ANY help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

OK, got it working. Here's what I did.

env.rb added:

```
require "selenium-webdriver"
```

and changed my steps with 'visit root_url' to:

```
visit root_path
```

I think that's everything I changed.

I honestly thought I'd tried that (and every other permutation of every other issue/fix I've seen). Can't believe I've wasted 3 days on this then found the answer just hours after posting the question publicly.

Comment: Does it mean you are using "path" instead of "url" in every test? Or did you find a better way (maybe tweaking the host or something?)

Comment: yes I'm using _path instead of _url. I'm not certain if it's the 'right' way to do it but it works for now.

Comment: According to the jnicklas, you want to make sure you are using _path and not _url as it has may have unintended consequences.